# Zf3 Zfcuser redirect param does not work

Tags: zend-framework2, zfcuser, zf3

Zfcuser provide an option to redirect to specified route with query param "redirect" like that:

```
/user/login?redirect=/en/about
```

Zfcuser 1.* version on ZF2 works perfectly. But recently I migrate to ZF3 and Zfcuser 2.0.0 version and noticed that this functionality does not work.

Everything is configured properly. Does some one experienced same problem?

Answer (score 0):

I made more research to the problem and it appears that the module does not support passing an uri as redirect param. It accepts only named routes. Also there is a problem with encoding and when using route like "home/about" it fails becouse of the "/" which is urlencoded and should be decoded.

I forked the module repo and fixed this. Also provided an option to pass not only named routes but and specific uri
 https://github.com/ivok/ZfcUser/tree/redirect

Comment: Passing URI is a security vulnerability, please have a look at @geeh's explanations of the OWASP top 10 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qMkiZ3Ehv5M), possibly one of the easiest talk on this subject. Using only named routes is just like having a sort of whitelist and protect you and your users.

Comment: I did not know that. I watched the lecture.

Comment: But what I am thinking now. When we passed some URL as redirect parameter, the router of the framework is trying to match the route and then load the content. So if you pass not valid URI or some query that is some kind of threat to our site, the router will not match it and will return 404 or whatever. If it does it, then the problem is other. But in our case, when I passed a redirect URI, the first thing to do is to validate that URI - is the route matches this url or not. If it does not - it sets to null and this redirect param is gone. Bu if it does, so the URI is valid.